# Hidding the post on wall when clicking the like o facebook button

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a project where I require to display the like button in a upside down on hover effect, said this, when people click like I need it doesn't display the dialog to write something to post on your wall, instead only like it and mark the counting.

here is the link, [the link](http://andresmijares.com/projects/stage2/wireframe/lookbook.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with a little but of css to hide the DOM element that Facebook adds.

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment span.fb_edge_comment_widget {
display: none !important;}
```